# Find all array with second highest elements in a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

Assuming that I have a list of arrays in Python `3.2`, and I want to output an array that contains *every* array elements, together with their index position in the list, which have the highest *second* elements. How can I achieve this goal in the most scalable way (i.e., without having to use the nested `for`-loop )?

**Input**

```
a = [[2,3], [1,4,5], [1,4,6,2], [3,3,5], [9,4]]
```

**Expected Output**

```
res = [[[1,4,5], 1], [[1, 4, 6,2], 2], [[9,4], 4]]
```

Can someone please help assist me on how to do this without using nested `for`-loop?

Comment: Do you know the second highest element before hand? ie in this case do you know that its 4? Or do you have to look for it? Are your arrays ordered in any way?

Comment: Great questions. Unfortunately, in this case, the answers to your first and third questions are No. The answer to the second question is YES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
b = max(a, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]  
[[j, i] for i, j in enumerate(a) if j[1]==b]
Out[6]: [[[1, 4, 5], 1], [[1, 4, 6, 2], 2], [[9, 4], 4]]
```